# Pattern Matcher not working for whiteSpace

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to search below word using pattern Matcher java

Word to search in doc:

```
 (peak: somevalue) [
```

code:

```
Matcher m= Pattern.compile("\\(peak:(.*?)\\)\\s[").matcher(currLine);
```

but not getting the expected result.

want to get value of "somevalue" using the pattern, could you please guide me.

Comment: you may also want to comment mask "[", since it is a regexp part

Comment: This is the problem `\(peak:(.*?)\)\s[  <-- Unbalanced  '['` should be `\(peak:(.*?)\)\s\[`

Answer (score 1):

This code gives you the correct result:

```
    String s="(peak: somevalue) [";
    Matcher m= Pattern.compile("\\(peak:(.*?)\\)\\s\\[").matcher(s);

    m.find();
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape `[` at the end of your regex because it is also one of its metacharacter used to create `[...]` [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

```
Pattern.compile("\\(peak:(.*?)\\)\\s\\[")
//here -----------------------------^^
```

and you can add `\\s?` before `(.*?)` to not include space after `peak:` in match from group 1.

So your code can look like

```
Matcher m =  Pattern.compile("\\(peak:\\s?(.*?)\\)\\s\\[").matcher(currLine);
if(m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
//                            ^^^ group 1 will contain match from `(.*?)`
```

BTW it looks like instead of regex you should be using parser of language you are trying to analyse. Regex can give you many problems like false-positive matches if you use `.*?` because dot `.` can accept any character so in your case pattern `"\\(peak:\\s?(.*?)\\)\\s\\["` will accept any string which starts with `(peak:` and ends with `) [` like `(peak:whatever)()<foo>{bar}{}(blah) [`.

To solve this kind of problem you will need to be more specific with what kind of characters should be accepted as `whatever`. One of ideas is to let it accept characters which are not `)` so you could try with

```
Pattern.compile("\\(peak:\\s?([^)]*?)\\)\\s\\[")
//                            ^^^^ means any character except `)`
```

Comment: \(peak:(.*?)\)\s\[  - not working as expected, i need to search for (peak:somevalue) [  but with the above code it also searches for (peak:somevalue) <br>asdbsadsdb[   which gives me incorrect result, is it possible to search only the pattern (peak:somevalue) [

Comment: @user3387870 check my updated answer. If it is not what you are looking for then edit your question and include some examples of input and explain which values should be matcher and which not. (Let me know if you edit your question.)

Comment: my search value is like below: (peak:360) [                                   but i get result as from different line which also has this kind of pattern                                                                    Line 1: (peak:360) [                                                   Line2: (peak:480) foobarsomewordsintegers [   so i get two results

Comment: @user3387870 Sorry I am not sure what you mean. Consider editting your question with examples of input and results you want to get (which elements should be matched, which not, and why).

Comment: I need to get the value  "360" from ex:(peak:360) [  in some line but i also have same kind of pattern (peak:520) foobar [ , in my result i get two results , i want to filter it out the exact pattern (peak:xxx) [

Comment: @user3387870 Like I said earlier, I am not sure what your problem is because regex from my answer `\\(peak:\\s?([^)]*?)\\)\\s\\[` seems to do exactly what you want http://regex101.com/r/xH9tP4/2 (it matches `(peak:360) [` and finds `360` in group 1, and it doesn't match - filters out - `(peak:520) foobar [`).

Answer (score 0):

You need a \s between your colon and the "anything capture" of (.*?)

Comment: He put the desired value he wanted to capture in double quotes.  I don't see a leading whitespace.

Comment: You're right, he did say what he wanted to capture.